# What is the equivalent of document.createTextNode(' ') in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What can I use in jquery instead of `document.createTextNode(' ')` js line.

I'm trying to do sth like this :

js : `divButtons.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));`

jquery : `$("#divButtons").append(?????);`

Comment: But it's about createElement function not createTextNode

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Please be careful with the existing answers. They show how to append HTML. HTML is not Text. Treating text as HTML is a) a bug and b) dangerous.

Here is a sane solution:

```
$('selector').append(document.createTextNode('text < and > not & html!'))
```

This is using jQuery only for the append part. Nothing wrong with using createTextNode. jQuery uses createTextNode internally in its `text(str)` function.

Answer (score 10):

```
var jqTextNode = $(document.createTextNode(' '));
```

creates the jquery representation of a text node. i don't think there is a shortcut which works reliable.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I was looking for the same thing...

The closest method that I'm aware of is the .text() method.

This escapes text securely in the same way as creating a new TextNode, but it can only be used to specify the full contents of a node.

e.g.

```
var mynode = jQuery('#node-id');
mynode.text('A<B implies B>A');
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no equivalent in jQuery for `createTextNode`. You can always use the DOM method, or write a jQuery wrapper around it. The closest thing you may be able to find is when creating new elements, you can specify the text part separately.

```
$('<div>', {
    text: '<hello world>'
});
```